# How to make advanced CMS-like blog system from scratch?

Tags: node.js, web, content-management-system, blogs, feed

When you create a news or blog tab with CMS it's really easy to make a feed of posts with content preview. Also when you follow a link to a particular post you can notice that it consists of a different html tags and css styling and not just plain text. It just uses rich text editor. So just getting text from db is not enough.

My question is how to achieve the same result when making a website from scratch. It doesn't matter what language is used for back-end. I'm just interested in the idea how to do it. But if you could provide a code examples (with any language) it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've figured it out. Posting the answer for somebody who will have the similar question in the future.

The idea is that you need to put a text with html tags into your database and then to retrieve it you need to put it in your desired div in unescaped state. The thing is that almost all view (template) engines escape html tags by default. To do that you have to use some built in functions specific to that view engine.

To put the article with html tags in db you can just write raw html into input field or you can somehow add richtext editor to input field. Richtext editor will generate html for you.

I've researched it and found out that that's exactly how cms work.

So there you have it. If you want to add something feel free to do it